# How do I make tf.Variable() objects tracktable in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

In the code below, I defined the **temperature** by tf.Variable() and multiplies by **attn** which is an output of convolutional operations. And it works well until the training process, but AssertionError occurs as below when saving the model.

How can I make tf.Variable() object **temperature** tracktable?

[image]

```
class MDTA(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_heads):
        super(MDTA, self).__init__()
        self.num_heads = num_heads
     
    def build(self, inputs):
        b, h, w, c = inputs.shape
        
        # --------------------  Layers  -------------------- 
        qkv = Conv2D(filters=c*3, kernel_size=1, use_bias=False) 
        qkv_conv = Conv2D(c*3, kernel_size=3, padding='same', groups=c*3, use_bias=False)
        project_out = Conv2D(filters=c, kernel_size=1, use_bias=False)

        temperature = tf.Variable([[[[1.]] for _ in range(self.num_heads)]], 
        shape=[None, self.num_heads, 1, 1], trainable=True)
        
        # --------------------  forward  -------------------- 
        q, k, v = tf.split(qkv_conv(qkv(inputs)), num_or_size_splits=3, axis=-1)
        
        # divide the # of channels into heads & learn separate attention map
        q = tf.reshape(q, [-1, self.num_heads, c//self.num_heads, h * w])  # (N, num_heads, C/num_heads, HW)
        k = tf.reshape(k, [-1, self.num_heads, c//self.num_heads, h * w])
        v = tf.reshape(v, [-1, self.num_heads, c//self.num_heads, h * w])
        
        q, k = tf.nn.l2_normalize(q, axis=-1), tf.nn.l2_normalize(k, axis=-1)

        # CxC Attention map instead of HWxHW (when num_heads=1)
        attn = tf.matmul(q, k, transpose_b=True) 
        attn = multiply([attn, temperature])
        attn = Softmax(axis=-1)(attn)
        
        out = tf.matmul(attn, v)
        shape = [tf.shape(out)[k] for k in range(4)]  # [Batch, num_heads, c/num_heads, H*W]
        out = tf.reshape(out,  [shape[0], h, w, shape[1]*shape[2]])
        out = project_out(out)  # attn*v: (N, num_heads, C/num_heads, HW)
        return out
    
    def __call__(self, inputs):
        return self.build(inputs)
```

I revised the process of defining and multiplying **Temperature** as below, but it did not work.

```
class Temp(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_heads):
        super(Temp, self).__init__()
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.temp = tf.Variable([[[[1.]]for _ in range(self.num_heads)]], 
                                shape=tf.TensorShape([None, self.num_heads, 1, 1]),validate_shape=False, trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        outputs = multiply([inputs, self.temp])
        return outputs
```

Comment: AssertionError: Tried to export a function which references an 'untracked' resource. TensorFlow objects (e.g. tf.Variable) captured by functions must be 'tracked' by assigning them to an attribute of a tracked object or assigned to an attribute of the main object directly. See the information below: